# Extra gigabit ethernet to raspberry PI B+

Tags: ethernet, ethernet-port

I'm looking for extra gigabit ethernet. I need 4 EXTRA ethernet ports on my raspberry. Can anyone help me? Is there a breakout board with the chip lan7515?

Comment: Buy a router, job done.

Comment: Better a 5 port switch?

Comment: The real question is, why do you want 5 ethernet ports on a raspberry pi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is why you need 5 Gb ports on a 1.5 GHz machine.  No way a r-pi can handle or generate that much data.

If the 5 port ethernet switch Ingo proposed to you isn't what you need, your best bet is to buy a big USB hub and plug 4 USB - ethernet adapters in.
I believe onboard ethernet adapter is USB (but I'm not positive), so you would get about the same speed from each.

Comment: In addition: on a Raspberry Pi B3+ the ethernet port is called "gigabit" but in fact it can only handle max. 300 MB on this port due to emulation with the USB chip. That's the bottle neck and must be shared.